# how to add search field to navigation bar's title in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

[how to make a similiar design using Navigatiion drawer template activity ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glaYO.png)

Comment: Define your own `AppBar` and include `EditText` in it.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: You can do it using `SearchView`. Add a SearchView in the layout, add a layout in toolbar (`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`, also add android.support.v7 in your project) and  set toolbar as `supportActionBar`.

Answer (score 0):

try this xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.simple.activity.MainActivity">

 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/myAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                  android:queryHint="@string/search_hint"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:theme="@style/AppTheme.SearchView" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp"/>
         </FrameLayout>
       </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```